# Having issue with htmlspecialchars mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

What is wrong with this code...?? If i retrived data from mysql with the following code,it gives error.

```
$sql="select id,
        '" . htmlspecialchars(question, ENT_QUOTES) . "',
        '" . htmlspecialchars(option1, ENT_QUOTES) . "',
        '" . htmlspecialchars(option2, ENT_QUOTES) . "',
        '" . htmlspecialchars(option3, ENT_QUOTES) . "',
        '" . htmlspecialchars(option4, ENT_QUOTES) . "',
        '" . htmlspecialchars(correctAnswer, ENT_QUOTES) . "',
         '" . htmlspecialchars(category, ENT_QUOTES) . "',
          '" . htmlspecialchars(section, ENT_QUOTES) . "',
           '" . htmlspecialchars(chapter, ENT_QUOTES) . "'
           from $user order by id";
```

Comment: What is the error you were getting? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: I think you misused the variable $user . You must use only DB field name.

Comment: @Prabhu `$user` is substituted by php.

Comment: htmlspecialchars is for HTML, not SQL. You need mysqli_real_escape_string, or to use parameterised queries

Comment: If you think `htmlspecialchars` protects against SQL injections, that you’re wrong. They don’t.

Comment: Actually, looking again, I think you've fundamentally misunderstood how SQL works. You seem to be treating it as though PHP will be interpreting the query, when the reality is that an SQL query is just a string sent to the database server. Learn SQL on its own first, then learn how to safely plug it into PHP.

Comment: Most helpful would be if you post ur table structure and what you want get off it

Comment: Actually,when i enter data from fckeditor to mysql,it saves as a <p>abc</p>,When i retrive that data from mysql into php ,it will print same as <p>...</p>,and i dont want this..

Answer (score 4):

There are some issues here...

**My Wallet Problem: Some $$$ missing <sub>(sorry, bad pun, I know)</sub>:**

```
$sql="select id,
    '" . htmlspecialchars($question, ENT_QUOTES) . "',
    '" . htmlspecialchars($option1, ENT_QUOTES) . "',
    '" . htmlspecialchars($option2, ENT_QUOTES) . "',
    '" . htmlspecialchars($option3, ENT_QUOTES) . "',
    '" . htmlspecialchars($option4, ENT_QUOTES) . "',
    '" . htmlspecialchars($correctAnswer, ENT_QUOTES) . "',
     '" . htmlspecialchars($category, ENT_QUOTES) . "',
      '" . htmlspecialchars($section, ENT_QUOTES) . "',
       '" . htmlspecialchars($chapter, ENT_QUOTES) . "'
       from $user order by id";
```

**Quoting issue**

Look at [the answer of @bhawin, and give a +1 for spotting that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18418110/1667004)!

Single quote `'` is for enclosing strings, while the backtick `` ` is for enclosing names of SQL objects: columns, tables, etc...

**Using PHP basic mysql functions**

Newer PHP deprecated it. Don't do it... [Use PDO for fun and profit!](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

**Using string concatenation to assemble query**

SQL Injection... Not funny to get attacked that way. Even if using PDO, you have to know how to use prepared statements properly...

**htmlspecialchars in query -- why?**

This escapes the string to be safely displayed in HTML pages. Not for building queries... That is what `mysql_real_escape_string` is for - but again, use PDO instead of the whole ordeal.

**Relying on default encoding**

Use UTF-8 (or the encoding you chose for the task) explicitly and consistently wherever deailng with strings. Like:

```
htmlspecialchars($correctAnswer, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
```

**And finally**

Why on Earth are you specifying the column names this way? It doesn't make sense.

If your intent was to sanitize the **results** from the query, you should do that *after* retrieving the results... And suddenly, `htmlspecialchars` starts to make sense!

Comment: While these are useful points, I think the last sentence is the one which is actually most important: the entire way the OP is approaching the problem is incorrect.

Comment: @IMSoP Honestly, I can't even figure out what and how is going on with the original post, these all are just shots in the dark...

Comment: Yeah, I think there's some pretty deep misunderstandings leading up to this code :)

Answer (score 2):

> You are trying to escape the column name ? you escape values inserted to database , not column names or values already in database.

htmlspecialchars to select from table in mysql? htmlspecialchars is fot html not sql.  you escape value when you insert them to database not when you selecting them . they already in database so why escape them ?

try this

```
     $sql="select id,
    question,
    option1,
    option2,
    option3, 
    option4, 
    correctAnswer,
     category, 
      section, 
     chapter 
       from $user order by id";
```

Comment: This is something I've been thinking about a couple of times: I'd rather store the contents in the DB verbatim (just SQL escaped), and escaped on retrieval if needed, e.g when displaying content in HTML page, but without malicious content.

Comment: you escape it when inserting them to database. and when they r in database they saFE. just retrive them normal

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql="select `id`,
    `" . htmlspecialchars(question, ENT_QUOTES) . "`,
    `" . htmlspecialchars(option1, ENT_QUOTES) . "`,
    `" . htmlspecialchars(option2, ENT_QUOTES) . "`,
    `" . htmlspecialchars(option3, ENT_QUOTES) . "`,
    `" . htmlspecialchars(option4, ENT_QUOTES) . "`,
    `" . htmlspecialchars(correctAnswer, ENT_QUOTES) . "`,
     `" . htmlspecialchars(category, ENT_QUOTES) . "`,
      `" . htmlspecialchars(section, ENT_QUOTES) . "`,
       `" . htmlspecialchars(chapter, ENT_QUOTES) . "`
       from $user order by id";
```

i just changed ' to ` in query

Comment: There is much more wrong with this code than a few apostrophes!

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're trying to do, but you're going about it completely the wrong way. When you build an SQL query to send to the database, that SQL query is just a string, and contains no functionality. You can build it however you like, but the database will only see the resulting string.

In your code, you have a whole set of lines like this: `htmlspecialchars(question, ENT_QUOTES)` which are being interpretted **by PHP** to build up the query. PHP has a somewhat dubious feature that an unquoted name like `question` could be a constant, but if it's not will be assumed to be the string `'question'`; the string `'question'` has no instances of `<`, `>`, `&`, `"`, or `'` in it, so `htmlspecialchars` will leave it untouched regardless of the options you pass in. In short, writing `htmlspecialchars(question, ENT_QUOTES)` is the same as writing `'question'`.

You're then concatenating (`.`) that fixed string with another fixed string containing some single-quotes: `".... '" . htmlspecialchars(question, ENT_QUOTES) . "' ...."`

So your query actually ends up like this:

```
 $sql="select id,
'question',
'option1',
'option2',
'option3', 
'option4', 
'correctAnswer',
'category', 
'section', 
'chapter'
from $user order by id";
```

The next odd thing you have is that the table you are selecting *from* is designated with a variable. Table names don't generally change, so there isn't generally a need for a variable, although it can be useful occasionally to configure them. If that's what you're doing, I would advise a more explicit variable name, like `$db_table_name_user`.

Looking at the column names, though, they don't look like columns of a user, so I wonder if what your actually trying to do is retrieve from a table of questions based on some particular user. For that, you will need a `WHERE` clause, or possibly to `JOIN` onto another table. Read up on SQL if you don't know how those work.

Assuming that `$user` contains the name of the database table, though, the above will actually run as a successful SQL query - just not a particularly useful one, since it will select out the `id` of each user, along with the literal strings `'question'`, `'option1'`, etc. You need to either remove those, or replace them with back-ticks, which are what MySQL uses to quote column and table names to avoid them being interpreted as something else.

This will retrieve the details of everything in the `user` table, assuming that's what it is:

```
 $db_table_name_user = 'user';

 $sql="select id,
 question,
 option1,
 option2,
 option3, 
 option4, 
 correctAnswer,
 category, 
 section, 
 chapter 
 from $user order by id";
```

Now we come to what you were actually trying to achieve with `htmlspecialchars`: handling escaping in the **content** you get back from the database. This has nothing to do with how you write the query, only to do with what you do afterwards. Your database table should store the exact text entered: when you insert it to the DB, you will use `mysqli_real_escape_string` (or a parameterised prepared query) to make sure the database doesn't interpret it as part of the query, but that is just about how you send it, not how it is stored.

Then, when you are actually *displaying* the text on an HTML page, after you've retrieved it from the database, you will escape it so that the *browser* doesn't interpret it as part of the markup. Escaping should generally happen as late as possible, so that you don't have to make assumptions about whether some string has already been escaped or not.

For instance, for a numbered list of questions, the code would be something like this:

```
 $all_questions = get_all_questions_from_db();
 echo '<ol>';
 foreach ( $all_questions as $question )
 {
      echo '<li>' . htmlspecialchars($question['question']) . '</li>';
 }
 echo '</ol>';
```